# How to specify a range for source ports for Nmap

Tags: nmap

It seems source port option "-g" does not support a range of ports, but destination port "-p" does. Has anyone came across a way to scan a fixed destination port using a range of source ports?

This works
nmap -g 4565 -p 1000-1020 -sS target

But this does not
nmap -g 4565-5000 -p 1000 -sS target

I understand one can simply loop through the source ports, but i'm curious if this can be done using a nmap script to better improve the output report.